# Can RKHS of Gaussian kernels over $\mathbb{R}^d$ have a non-zero element which is zero on a linear subspace $R^k\subset R^d$ where $k>0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I have been thinking on this problem for at least a day now, and I thought the answer is a resounding no. It seems I am wrong, but wanted to double-check. I came across [this](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.595.9029&rep=rep1&type=pdf):[image]

And from my understanding assuming that WLOG one can take any linear subspace to be $\mathbb{R}^k$ with $k$ elements of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^d$, this technically means if $f\in\mathcal{H}_k(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and it is the case that the non-zero coefficients of a given $f$ tend to coincide with the elements of the basis that have their $\alpha_i\neq 0$ for some $i\leq k$, and the rest of the coefficients are zero would be an example of such a function. So the answer is a resounding yes, I guess?

**UPDATE:** My solution definitely is not right. In fact what I call WLOG is not at all WLOG. But I would appreciate any guidance/help towards whether the answer to this question is positive or negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to be the issue? The result you quote explains that the RKHS has a basis of square-exponentially weighted polynomials. You can take any set $V$ defined by a finite number of polynomial equations and the whole bunch of polynomial functions will vanish on that set (the ideal of the corresponding affine variety); multiplying them by squared-exponential weight won't change the vanishing. So you will have a lot of functions in the RKHS vanishing on $V$ (and more of them when you take the completion, but we don't even need to go there for what you are asking).

Comment: Thank you that solves my problem. I was not even aware of ideals for polynomials. And what my primitive knowledge, such ideals do not exist in one dimension, but as you go higher they start to be pretty typical.

Comment: Also my situation is that $V$ is actually $d-1$ dimensional. Does that make any difference? Is there any place I can look for that particular case? I asked the question in generality, but that was my particular question actually.

Comment: Dimension of V makes no difference here.

Comment: I reread your answer and now it does make more sense to me. But still I am confused why the dimension doesn't matter? For example if $V$ is exactly $d$-dimensional there is only one element of the RKHS zero over it, namely the zero function. So the dimension should play a restricting role in number of vanishing polynomials in the RKHS. No?

Comment: Yes, what I mean is as long as we have a proper algebraic subvariety its dimension does not matter. The "proper" excludes exactly the case you describe of having V equal to the whole space. It also excludes anything that is not all of R^n but contains an open set of the original R^n (such a thing can not be defined by a set of polynomials, i.e. is not a subvariety).

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification. I think I understand what you mean far better now. Maybe I wasn't clear but by restriction on meant in terms of a measure over the RKHS, to put it loosely (what I mean is Gaussian Processes). So my expectation is that the measure of the set of functions that vanish over such a set should be affected by the dimension of that subspace. Maybe I need to open a new question for that. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: The set of functions vanishing on a given affine subvariety will be an infinite-dimensional subspace of the infinite-dimensional RKHS. There may be a sense in which some of those are bigger or smaller, but it's not obvious what that sense is (perhaps codimension). Maybe you were thinking about how big these vanishing spaces are in terms of the measure that the GP induces on function spaces, but that is problematic since the probability of getting any function in the RKHS when sampling from GP (much less the one vanishing on V) is zero.

Comment: Thank you for taking all the time to give me detailed explanation. In fact I meant it in terms of the measure induced by GP, and yes sampling an exact function from GP has a zero probability. But what I am thinking about is what is the measure for the sets of functions that differ from zero function only on a measure zero set. That should have a well-defined answer, I believe. Do you think I should open a new question for that? Thanks again!

Comment: I mean something much stronger. The probability of the RKHS is zero. The sample lies outside of the RKHS with probability one. See, for example, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.02582.pdf

Comment: Thanks @Max! I have seen that article. Exactly in the same article it gives some mild conditions that guarantees the existence of a "version" of RKHS elements for GP. And versions of RKHS elements are modifications of the elements up to measure zero. From what I understand Theorem 4.9 in paper you mentioned explains exactly that.

Comment: The version is of the GP, not of RKHS elements (a priori the space on which GP lives has no measure, so the other way is not even defined). I would say the conditions are not so mild.

Comment: I am not sure why my comment brought me to this page. I am assuming to many comments. You're absolutely right. A version of GP, but I don't think that changes the nature of the problem. Essentially what I am asking is $\mu(\left\{f\middle| \forall v\in V\ f(v)=0\ a.s.\right\})$, where $\mu$ is the measure induced by the GP.